# Associate / Relate two numericupdown buttons

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program in VB .NET which two numericupdown buttons should be associated, if value in samp button is changed max should also be controlled and vice a versa. I have written code for it but somehow it is not working perfectly. Please let me what I am missing here.

samp Minimum is set to 50 and Maximum 400; while
max Minimum is set is 0 and Maximum 350

```
Private Sub samp_changed() Handles config_samp.ValueChanged

If config_samp.Value <= 400 And config_samp.Value >= 299 Then
   config_max.Value = 150
End If

If config_samp.Value <= 300 And config_samp.Value >= 199 Then
   config_max.Value = 250
End If

If config_samp.Value <= 198 And config_samp.Value >= 50 Then
   config_max.Value = 350
End If

End Sub


Private Sub max_changed() Handles config_max.ValueChanged

If config_max.Value <= 350 And config_max.Value >= 251 Then
   config_samp.Value = 200
End If

If config_max.Value <= 250 And config_max.Value >= 151 Then
   config_samp.Value = 300
End If

If config_max.Value <= 150 And config_max.Value >= 101 Then
   config_samp.Value = 400
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add what behaiour you are experiencing please and how this differs from what you require?

Comment: If max reaches 150 then I cannot change samp below 400. The value 400 gets stuck there itself. Basically value increment / decrement is not smooth like samp value increases from 299 directly jumps to 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program executes `samp_changed()`, the .Value of `config_max` is changed, so it calls `max_changed()`, which might change the value of `config_samp`, which would mean that `samp_changed()` is called, and it gets locked in to one value eventually.

What you need to do is temporarily stop each method from causing the other to be called. You can do that by explicitly removing the handler, changing the value, and adding the handler.

Those `If config_max.Value <= 350 And config_max.Value >= 251 Then`, and so on, lines are a bit unwieldy. It would be easier to see what is going on by using a [`Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) statement, something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub samp_changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim newMaxValue = 0
        Dim valueChanged = False

        Select Case config_samp.Value
            Case 50 To 198
                newMaxValue = 350
                valueChanged = True
            Case 199 To 300
                newMaxValue = 250
                valueChanged = True
            Case 299 To 400
                newMaxValue = 150
                valueChanged = True
        End Select

        If valueChanged Then
            RemoveHandler config_max.ValueChanged, AddressOf max_changed
            config_max.Value = newMaxValue
            AddHandler config_max.ValueChanged, AddressOf max_changed
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub max_changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim newSampValue = 0
        Dim valueChanged = False

        Select Case config_max.Value
            Case 101 To 150
                newSampValue = 400
                valueChanged = True
            Case 151 To 250
                newSampValue = 300
                valueChanged = True
            Case 251 To 350
                newSampValue = 200
                valueChanged = True
        End Select

        If valueChanged Then
            RemoveHandler config_samp.ValueChanged, AddressOf samp_changed
            config_samp.Value = newSampValue
            AddHandler config_samp.ValueChanged, AddressOf samp_changed
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler config_samp.ValueChanged, AddressOf samp_changed
        AddHandler config_max.ValueChanged, AddressOf max_changed

    End Sub

End Class
```